How to redirect my IP to domain name -Coturn
We're running coturn in the following environment:

EC2 on a public subnet with a public and private interface
coturn running in Docker, via AWS ECS

Notably, we do not have a load balancer or NAT gateway in front of this instance. We have opened the security groups to allow all ports from all IPs.
When I test our instance via Trickle ICE, I get the following:
0.072   srflx   3   udp x.x.x.x         52931   100 | 32287 | 255       
0.077   relay   5   udp 10.53.34.156    65525   5   | 32285 | 255       
0.089   srflx   3   udp x.x.x.x         65047   100 | 32287 | 254       
0.097   relay   5   udp 10.53.34.156    65501   5   | 32285 | 254   

Where x.x.x.x is correctly my public IP. However, the relay endpoint is the private IP from within our Docker container. My understanding of ICE is that this should be a public interface so that clients can use it for TURN sessions.
Here are our launch configs and startup commands:
0: (1): INFO: log file opened: /var/log/turn_1_2024-04-22.log
0: (1): INFO: System cpu num is 2
0: (1): INFO: System enable num is 1
0: (1): INFO: Listener address to use: 0.0.0.0
0: (1): INFO: Relay address to use: 0.0.0.0
0: (1): INFO: Coturn Version Coturn-4.6.2 'Gorst'
0: (1): INFO: Max number of open files/sockets allowed for this process: 1048576
0: (1): INFO: Due to the open files/sockets limitation, max supported number of TURN Sessions possible is: 524000 (approximately)
0: (1): INFO: 

==== Show him the instruments, Practical Frost: ====

0: (1): INFO: OpenSSL compile-time version: OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023 (0x30100040)
0: (1): INFO: TLS 1.3 supported
0: (1): INFO: DTLS 1.2 supported
0: (1): INFO: TURN/STUN ALPN supported
0: (1): INFO: Third-party authorization (oAuth) supported
0: (1): INFO: GCM (AEAD) supported
0: (1): INFO: SQLite supported, default database location is /var/lib/coturn/turndb
0: (1): INFO: Redis supported
0: (1): INFO: PostgreSQL supported
0: (1): INFO: MySQL supported
0: (1): INFO: MongoDB supported
0: (1): INFO: Default Net Engine version: 3 (UDP thread per CPU core)
0: (1): INFO: Domain name: 
0: (1): INFO: Default realm: gearbox.com
0: (1): ERROR: CONFIG: Empty cli-password, and so telnet cli interface is disabled! Please set a non empty cli-password!
0: (1): INFO: Certificate file found: /etc/coturn/cert.pem
0: (1): INFO: Private key file found: /etc/coturn/private-key.pem
0: (1): INFO: TLS cipher suite: ALL:!COMPLEMENTOFDEFAULT:!eNULL:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
0: (1): INFO: DTLS cipher suite: ALL:!COMPLEMENTOFDEFAULT:!eNULL:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
0: (1): INFO: pid file created: /var/run/turnserver.pid
0: (1): INFO: IO method: epoll (with changelist)
0: (1): INFO: RFC5780 disabled! /NAT behavior discovery/
0: (1): INFO: Wait for relay ports initialization...
0: (1): INFO:   relay 0.0.0.0 initialization...
0: (1): INFO:   relay 0.0.0.0 initialization done
0: (1): INFO: Relay ports initialization done
0: (1): INFO: Total General servers: 2
0: (14): DEBUG: turn server id=1 created
0: (13): DEBUG: turn server id=0 created
0: (1): INFO: Total auth threads: 3
0: (15): INFO: SQLite DB connection success: /var/lib/turn/turndb
0: (1): INFO: prometheus collector disabled, not started

Our startup command:
sudo docker run -d -v /root/config/turnserver.conf:/etc/coturn/turnserver.conf \
                   -v /root/ssl/private-key.pem:/etc/coturn/private-key.pem \
                   -v /root/ssl/cert.pem:/etc/coturn/cert.pem \
                   --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/var/lib/coturn \
                   --network=host \
                   -p 3478-3479:3478-3479 -p 3478-3479:3478-3479/udp \
                   -p 443:443 -p 443:443/udp \
                   -p 65500-65535:65500-65535/udp \
                   -e DETECT_EXTERNAL_IP=yes \
                   -e DETECT_RELAY_IP=yes \
                   coturn-gbx \
                   --min-port=65500 \
                   --max-port=65535 \
                   --no-multicast-peers \
                   --no-tlsv1 --no-tlsv1_1 \
                   --realm=company.com

Question: Should our relay endpoint be public? If so, what are we doing wrong here?

Yes,for Coturn to function effectively as a TURN server, especially when used to support WebRTC applications, the relay endpoint is accessible via public IP address.
From your description and the settings, I would double check the following to ensure that the relay endpoint uses a public IP:
External IP Detection: You mentioned using the environment variable DETECT_EXTERNAL_IP=yes. Sometimes, auto-detection might not work as expected due to some weirdness with network configurations or Docker's networking mode. You may need to explicitly set the external IP in the Coturn configuration or startup command.
Configuration Settings: Double check that the external IP is correctly configured in the turnserver.conf file or as a command-line argument.
Security Groups and Network ACLs: Double check that your AWS EC2 security groups and network ACLs are configured to allow incoming and outgoing traffic on the necessary ports. Since you're using a wide range of ports (3478-3479 for TURN and 65500-65535 for relay), these need to be open to both TCP and UDP traffic as required.
Explicit IP Configuration: If automatic detection is not cooperating, consider explicitly setting both the listening and relay IP addresses in your Coturn configuration to the public IP of the EC2 instance.
Based on the OP, here's a modified version of your Docker command with explicit external IP settings (replace  and  with actual IP addresses):
sudo docker run -d -v /root/config/turnserver.conf:/etc/coturn/turnserver.conf \
                -v /root/ssl/private-key.pem:/etc/coturn/private-key.pem \
                -v /root/ssl/cert.pem:/etc/coturn/cert.pem \
                --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/var/lib/coturn \
                --network=host \
                -p 3478-3479:3478-3479 -p 3478-3479:3478-3479/udp \
                -p 443:443 -p 443:443/udp \
                -p 65500-65535:65500-65535/udp \
                -e DETECT_EXTERNAL_IP=no \
                -e DETECT_RELAY_IP=no \
                coturn-gbx \
                --external-ip=<your-public-ip>/<your-private-ip> \
                --min-port=65500 \
                --max-port=65535 \
                --no-multicast-peers \
                --no-tlsv1 --no-tlsv1_1 \
                --realm=company.com
```

